# Will I be able to upgrade from 22.10 to 23.04?

Tags: upgrade

I am on 22.10 and was wondering if I'll be able to upgrade to 23.04 on April 20th? Thank you!

Comment: Yes you will be able to upgrade, that is the expected path for your system.. it's available now (with the `-d` flag) too, however the *taps* for the upgrade are not turned on until AFTER the Ubuntu Release team opens the *tap*, and that often doesn't occur until early-mid the next week after ISO release (ISO release being for new installs).

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *lunar* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 April 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 April 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-schedule/27284  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *lunar* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)  *I answered your question, but sorry I still see it as off-topic being about a development release*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will be able to upgrade, that is the expected upgrade path for your system..

It's available now (*with the [`-d` flag](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development)*) too, however the '*taps*' for the upgrade are not turned on until **AFTER** the Ubuntu Release team decides its 'ready' for upgrade and opens the [*tap*](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release), and that often doesn't occur until early-mid the next week **after** ISO release (*ISO release being for new installs*).

ISO release date is 20-April-2023; [schedule is here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-schedule/27284) but that does **not** mean the upgrade path opens that day (*though it can be forced with `-d`*) but it'll open soon **after** as already explained.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I appreciate it!

Comment: You're most welcome.   FYI:  You can use it now, in fact I am in typing this...   This install was made back in February 2023 & I just upgrade it normally...   You can install using the *daily* ISOs too (*I'm running the 4th install for today on another nearby box for Quality Assurance purposes as I type this*), or as mentioned in the answer - *release-upgrade* early..  It's currently in [beta](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/31/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-beta-released/) so problems can occur, but aren't expected..